# empty response when using CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION

Tags: php, curl

I'm trying to get response headers using `CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION`

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION, function($curl, $headerLine) use($date) {
   file_put_contents('/tmp/response-headers.log', $date . " " . print_r($headerLine, true), FILE_APPEND);
});

$response = curl_exec($ch);
```

Received header is `HTTP/1.1 200 OK`, but `$response` is empty. However, when I comment out the `curl_setopt` function above, everything works fine and I get full response body.

How can I receive full body while dumping headers to file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation for CURLOPT_HEADERFUNCTION](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php) says

> A callback accepting two parameters. The first is the cURL resource, the second is a string with the header data to be written. The header data must be written by this callback. Return the number of bytes written.

Your function does not return the number of bytes written.